# Best practice on how to bundle tomcat with my application using install4j

Tags: tomcat, install4j

I am trying to create a installer using install4j for my application. I have a requirement where I need to ship tomcat with it, such as tomcat can be installed as a service once application gets installed. Please can someone suggest the best way to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the tomcat files to the distribution tree.

As for the service, you will have to create a generated launcher that mimics the behavior of catalina.bat.

Comment: Thanks Ingo for your answer. When you say tomcat files, do I need to add the unzipped files of tomcat or zip can work too ?

Comment: I would enter them unzipped. The installer will ZIP them for you. You can also add the ZIP and use an "Install content of a ZIP file" action.